# Chrome randomly inserting quotation marks in html

Tags: python, google-chrome, jinja2

I'm working on an app using Flask framework with Jinja2 templating and i noticed Chrome browser is randomly inserting quotation marks with several whitespaces inside html. It doesn't  happen on every page, and at this point i have no idea what might be causing it. Here's how it looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnWQr.png]. Can this be caused by templating engine?

Comment: You might have an unclosed tag somewhere. Your meta, title, link tags being rendered inside the body tag rather than the head tag.

Comment: I have triple checked tags in every page where this error occur and tags doesn't seem to have anything to do with it. Even if i delete all the content inside the template it still shows.

Comment: Just in case anyone happens to have similar problem, as i wrote below it is caused when encoding is not set properly, i must have set it to something other than utf-8 in one of the templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can this be caused by templating engine?

*absolutely*.  In jinja, if you want to remove whitespace, put a `-` inside your template directives.  e.g.:

```
{%- if foo -%}
    something
{%- endif -%}
```

Consider the difference between:

```
{% set foo=false %}
<div>
{%- if foo -%}
    something
{%- endif -%}
</div>
<div>
{% if foo %}
    something
{% endif %}
</div>
```

In one case, your div will have whitespace in it and in the other case it won't.

Comment: It works in that it removes all the whitespace inside the quotes, however the quotes itself are still there, even worse it seems completely random , I ran the generated code through W3C validator and it is valid html with all tags closed, also Firefox renders everything fine. At this moment I'm out of ideas  about what might be causing it.

Comment: The quotes aren't a problem (I don't think).  `<div></div>` is just a div with empty text (which is how the chrome developer panel displays it).  Without actually seeing some code, it's pretty hard to make a judgement call here.  However, looking at the HTML again, it seems a little weird to me that you have a bunch of tags which are generally included in `<head>` in the `<body>` -- That might be an issue.  What happens if you move that stuff out of the body and into the head?

Comment: All the link tags and meta tags are in the head, Chrome moves them straight into the body when it renders it, i have no idea why. I tried removing included js scripts from the page, that might have had causing this, but to no effect, Also interesting thing is Chrome always puts empty link tag inside head when it moves all that stuff out. I removed all the additional content from the page aswell as all the scripts, [This is how the code rendered by Chrome looks like](http://i.imgur.com/r00ja24.png), and [And this is page source](http://i.imgur.com/QI7brXH).

Comment: I have solved it. It was caused by wrong encoding, for some reason when you save HTML file with format other than utf 8 it happens. Thanks for help.